# tensorflow-dataset- How to make our own dataset with tfds format?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

From a TensorFlow tutorial , I came across a code that load dataset from TensorFlow dataset.

```
dataset, metadata = tfds.load('cycle_gan/horse2zebra',
                              with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_horses, train_zebras = dataset['trainA'], dataset['trainB']
test_horses, test_zebras = dataset['testA'], dataset['testB']
```

However, I want to load my own dataset that is not from TensorFlow dataset.
After collecting my own dataset, I had no idea how to load my dataset and process it to the same format as TensorFlow tfds.

Anyone can teach me how to do that?
My dataset folder also has the same format : trainA, trainB , testA , testB.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this tutorial to add a dataset to TFDS.

https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/docs/add_dataset.md

Comment: The true link should be: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset

Comment: Hello. The problem is: I don't understand the instruction and don't know to do it. I hope that there is an example.